# LVM encryption with manual partitioning for Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: partitioning, encryption, lvm, 23.04

Is there a way to LVM encrypt a volume when choosing manual partitioning in Ubuntu 23.04? I only see an encrypted volume if I let Ubuntu decide my partition tables for me:

[image]

If I select manual partitioning, there does not appear to be a way to achieve encryption. Screenshots in the installer:

[image]

In the old installer there would be an option to add to encrypted volume, this doesn't exist in 23.04:

[image]

Editing a proposed partition shows new options, but not encryption:

[image]

Summary of proposed partitions again shows no option for encryption. I can only go back or Install.

[image]

I'd strongly prefer doing this with GUI rather than encrypting things after the fact.

Apples and oranges, but in RHEL I'm able to check a box with the manual partition method and it encrypts the partitions with one step:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu maintains a version of 23.04 with the old installer. As of today (September 7th, 2023) you can find that installer listed on their [download page](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop#:%7E:text=Download%2023.04%20(Legacy%20Desktop%20Installer)), or download it directly at [this link](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/lunar/release/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso).

I hope this helps!